# activity still appears after using finish

Tags: java, android

Activity does not finish after the finish

```
public class ThirdActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

        Log.d("TAG", "onCreate ThirdActivity.............................................");

        finish();
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWpk0.png)

Comment: Why are you calling `finish()` in `onCreate()`? If you close an activity before it is created, then the activity is entirely useless. You either need to call `finish()` from some other function, such as a button click handler, or you need to use something other than an activity to do what you want.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice There are times where finish in onCreate is appropriate.  For example, if your app requires you to be logged in, one way of doing this is to launch the LoginActivity.  Then the login activity would look for a pre-existing login, and if one is found launch the MainActivity and finish itself before showing.  Generally activities like this are doing conditional launches of other activities, and are referenced from outside the main activity (such as the launcher, or a simplified handler activity for a class of URLs).  It's definitely not unheard of to do this.

Comment: Of course generally activities like I described above don't set a UI unless they aren't finished, so they don't flash one.

Comment: This is the third screen. I just did it to test the finish. In my second screen I ask for permissions and then I need to close the activity, I know how to do this. I just have this problem of having an activity still visible even after the finish.

Comment: I saw that only on Android 11 it is showing the activity even after finishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

putting this in the manifest solved it for me

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```